# Why are TARS and CASE named as such?

Tags: interstellar

TARS and CASE are the two robots which are part of the Endurance crew.

The [Interstellar wiki](http://interstellarfilm.wikia.com/wiki/TARS) explains

> TARS is a former marine robot with angular limbs and a sarcastic attitude.

and [that](http://interstellarfilm.wikia.com/wiki/CASE)

> CASE is one of three former marine surplus robots, alongside TARS and KIPP, CASE first appeared within an alcove onboard the Endurance mission.

Is there a significance to the names of the robots, or why were they named as such? Are they unique serial numbers (similar to R2-D2 and C-3PO)? The fact that the names are written in all caps on their bodies lends weight to the idea that they may be acronyms.

I'm hoping for an in-universe answer if possible. It wouldn't make much sense for the military to name them after people who assisted in the creation of the film.

[image: TARS]

Comment: Minor note: didn't TARS first appear at the gate of the secret NASA base, decking Coop while Murph waited in the truck?

Comment: And written in Braille below, of course. Painted Braille, which means it's largely useless for blind people...
One theory posted on the wiki:
"Tars is an anagram for star. As he is the star of the robots and it's a spacy name. By the way the other two robots are kipp and case. Kipp is for kip Thorne who was the scientific advisor. Kipp has an extra p to lend case which is ok because he is a pile of parts anyway. With a p case is now an anagram for space."

Comment: Simple, TARS for TERMINATARS....

Comment: Here's my little theory: Take a look at TARkovsky's Solaris, especially the interior design: http://cdn1.sbnation.com/assets/4033679/4.jpg

Answer (score 8):

According to this [Wired article](http://www.wired.com/2014/11/interstellar-droids/) (which includes information from Nolan) the names do not stand for anything.

> While Christopher Nolan was making Interstellar, he decided to show a
>   model of the movie’s bots to his kids. They were extremely
>   disappointed. “That’s not a robot,” they told him. “That’s a box.”
>   Well, it’s true: Nolan’s intelligent machines, which he dreamed up
>   with production designer Nathan Crowley, look for all the universe
>   like slabs of metal. The main bot, named TARS (which doesn’t stand for
>   anything), might as well be a distant cousin of 2001‘s monolith. Then
>   again, nothing in Nolan’s world(s) is what it seems. “When I let my
>   kids play with the model, open it up, see different combinations,” he
>   says, “they started getting really excited.” Let’s peek inside the
>   box.

Comment: They may not stand for anything, but do they have any in-universe significance?